# Has this form of the heat equation been solved for the radiation boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, linear-pde, heat-equation

Below is a solution to a special form of the heat equation. I have found the postings on the heat equation and they are far above my head.  I tried to find a tag on Transport Theory for both heat and mass--because my solution would apply to either heat flow or mass transfer--and could not find one.  Inasmuch as this was a tough differential equation I would like to know if it has been solved before.  And if not could I get it published?  I think I can also solve the same equation except for the boundary condition at $x=0$ would be $C_o \exp(-at)$ where $a$ is a constant and $t$ is time. This would be an exponentially depletable source for mass transfer or heat transfer.  Thanks in advance. I hope you won't pull my question. Mike

###### Differential Equation

$$
D \frac{\partial^2(C)}{\partial x^2}-u\frac{\partial(C)}{\partial x}-k C=\frac{\partial(C)}{\partial t}
$$

###### Initial Condition

$$
C(x,0)=0
$$

###### Boundary Conditions

\begin{eqnarray*}
C(0,t)&=C_o\\
\frac{\partial(C(L,t) )}{\partial x}+ h C(L,t)&=0
\end{eqnarray*}

###### Solution

$$
\begin{split}
C(x,t)& =  C_o
\frac{\Bigg[(\tfrac{u}{2D}+h)\sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}(L-x)\right) + \frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}(L-x)\right)\Bigg]e^\frac{U X}{ 2D }}{(\frac{u}{2D}+h)\sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}L\right) + \frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{u^2+4Dk}}{2D}L\right)}\\
& -C_o\frac{2}{L}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha_n \sin(\alpha_n x)\exp\left(\frac{ux}{2D}-(\frac{u^2}{4D}+k+D\alpha_n^2)t\right)}{(\frac{k}{D}+({\frac{u}{2D}})^2+\alpha_n^2)(1-\frac{\sin(2 \alpha_n L)}{2 \alpha_n L})}
\end{split}
$$

$$Tan(\alpha_n L)+\frac{\alpha_n}{\frac{u}{2D}+h}=0$$

Comment: I have edited the question, please check I haven't messed anything up.

Comment: Same for me: I moved a round bracket to the numerator of the first fraction, and changed it to a square bracket. Please check if I have messed up anything.

Comment: You don't specify what the $\alpha_n$ are, which makes the solution incomplete. In any case, it looks like the result of using separation of variables, which is at the level of an exercise in an upper undergraduate PDE class (not only for the heat equation, but also for many more equations with constant coefficients). That's why I've voted to close.

Comment: Igor,  Thanks for your comments.  It was not quite that easy and I could not use separation of variables for the listed differential equation.  But there is a transformation that will take will take the above equation from four terms to two terms.  You are right I did use separation of variables but only through the back door.

Comment: Using integrating factor-like changes of variables to remove first-order terms with constant coefficients for parabolic equations is pretty standard.